# how to avoid overwriting when using cat command

Tags: bash

I trying to get the details of files inside several folders and add it to a file called aa.txt, but the content is overwritten when go to different folder.

How can I add it to the file without overwriting the previous content?

```sh
for folder in R1 R2 R3 R4 P1 P2 P3 P4 M1 M2 M3 M4 S1 S2 S3 S4
do
    cd $folder
    # run folowing commands in the folder

    ls -ltr | cat > ../aa.txt   
    echo " $folder done" >> ../Completed.text
    cd ..
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should append to the output file, using `>>`

```
ls -ltr | cat >> ../aa.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Oscars' answer, you can also omit the for loop.

```sh
find R1 R2 R3 R4 P1 P2 P3 P4 M1 M2 M3 M4 S1 S2 S3 S4 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ls -lrt {} \; > aa.txt
```

The difference between `>` and `>>` is that the former clears the file before writing content, the latter appends content to the file.